# Explanation about (jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is a code used in many userscripts:

```
function with_jquery(f) {
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
document.body.appendChild(script);
};
```

I understood everything in it except this line:

```
  script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
```

I knew that text content sets the text content of the script( of course), but I just can't understand everything after the `=`. shouldn't this be:

```
   script.textContent = string;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By wrapping the string with  `(` f.toString() `)(jQuery)` the user is setting up the string to be executed as an [immediately invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), with the jQuery object passed into that function.

We would expect, then, that `f.toString()` would look something like

```
function($){ [doing something...] }
```

So that the jQuery object will stand in for `$`

The new string will still have to be evaluated, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The function creates a script element with this code:

```
(content-of-f)(jQuery)
```

So if you pass a string containing a function (eg `function($) { do something }`) and the function gets executed while `jQuery` is passed for the `$`-parameter.

Answer (score 1):

anonymous function:

```
(function(){
  //Normal code goes here
})
```

The really interesting part is what happens when we add this right at the end:

```
();
```

Those two little brackets cause everything contained in the preceding parentheses to be 
executed immediately.

When you write `(jquery)()` as below:

```
(function(a){
  console.log(a === jquery); //Returns 'true'
})(jquery);
```

All references to ‘jquery’ in your code can be renamed to ‘a’. check this [**CHEK THIS**](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/)